# Disabling Game Link Menu via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

For school I need to configure an Active Directory windows server via PowerShell.
I need to make sure that the users in my domain can't see the game link menu.
I've found the option in the GUI to disable this, but I've found it nowhere in Powershell.

I've tried the followning:

```
New-GPLink -Name "Remove Games link from start menu" -Target "OU=Ontwikkeling,OU=Afdelingen,DC=$domain,DC=Local"

New-GPO -Name "Games" | Set-GPRegistryValue  -Disable -Name "Games" - "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\GameDVR"   -ValueName AppCaptureEnabled -Type DWord -Value 0   

 new-gpo -name "Games_Bar" | Set-GPRegistryValue -Disable -name "Games_Bar" -Key "HKCU\System\GameConfigStore"   -ValueName GameDVR_Enabled   -Type DWord
```

Hope y'all can help me!
Thanks!

Comment: Did you make any progress on this? I'm also really curious on disabling (without uninstalling) the Xbox Game Bar.